# Php Video Upload Script

Tags: php, html, forms, file-upload, directory

I am trying to allow users to upload videos via this form

```
       <form method='POST' name='uploadform' enctype='multipart/form-data' action=''>
                                Video: <input type='file' name='filename' /><br/>
                                       <input type='submit' name='cmdSubmit' value='Upload' />";
```

Then with this php script I am trying to move the videos into another folder for storage.

```
            if($_POST['cmdSubmit']){
                            $filename = basename($_FILES['filename']['name']);
                            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "videos/" . $filename);
                    }
```

The problem I am having is the video's are not being moved to my folder. I have done research on how to do this and have try many error solving methods but nothing is seeming to work so if you have any idea on what my problem is any help is appreciated.  The form works perfectly. Thanks....

I have searched google and youtube and can't find any really good articles on this if you know any that would be awesome too.

I tried to do troubleshooting by using this code..

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "videos/" . $filename)){
                                echo "This worked Successfully";

                            }else{
                                echo "Error";   
                            }
                    }
```

and it did not echo either statement....

Comment: add `if` condition like: `if (move_uploaded_file())`{} else { /* error**/}

Comment: k i will try and let you know thanks

Comment: Read the full video upload tutorial posted by me 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994847/uploading-videos-into-a-folder-and-its-link-to-database-using-php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the below `PHP` code
in this code you can have some `Restrictions` on Upload
you can set the Exts that you need to allow in upload..

`HTML` `FORM` CODE

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="upload_file.php" method="post"   enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="file">Filename:</label>
     <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

`PHP` CODE BELOW

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

For Any Other `Reference` kindly  Check Here `http://w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp` Or Post A Comment

Comment: I am trying to upload videos this looks like it for images ... am i mistaken?

Comment: you need to change the ext here as $allowedExts = array("mp4", "avi", "mp3", "vob");
like this

Comment: I tried your code and have the same problem none of the echos happened it said nothing and did nothing haha

Comment: note you need to give full permision to the folder you have mensioned "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

Comment: Where your code says ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000) ......... should i change those to "video/mp4" ??

Comment: does it not already have full permission .. sorry but how would i go about giving full permission?

Comment: right click the folder where you need to save the uploaded files and set permission

Comment: Thank you soo much i think i have it working so far cause of you when my rep allows my i will vote you up thank you!!!!!

Comment: thanks... i am in your heart i can all ways welcome to our community

Answer (score 1):

In php.ini Find and update as following:

```
post_max_size = 8M

upload_max_filesize = 2M

max_execution_time = 30

max_input_time = 60

memory_limit = 8M

Change to:

post_max_size = 750M

upload_max_filesize = 750M

max_execution_time = 5000

max_input_time = 5000

memory_limit = 1000M
```