# PHP - Reduce Image Size with my code

Tags: php

I've created a code to upload my image file.

But i need to reduce their MBytes… How can i do it?

Can someone explain to be and help me to create a good compression code?

```
               if(!empty($ads_file)) {

               $files = $_FILES['img_file'];
               $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg');

               foreach($files['name'] as $position => $file_name) {

                   $file_tmp = $files['tmp_name'][$position];
                   $file_size = $files['size'][$position];
                   $file_error = $files['error'][$position];

                   $file_ext = explode('.', $file_name);
                   $file_ext = strtolower(end($file_ext));

                   if(in_array($file_ext, $allowed)) {

                        if($file_error === 0) {

                           if($file_size <= 4097152) {

                               $file_name_new = uniqid('', true) . '.' . $file_ext;
                               $file_destination = 'im/pd/'. $file_name_new;

                               $colBanco=3;
                               $j=0;                                   

                               if ($j<$colBanco){
                                  $praBanco .="'".$file_destination."',";

                                  if(!empty($errors)) { 
                                        //don't sent to folder if there is errors.
                                  } else {
                                      move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $file_destination);  
                                  }                                         
                               }

                               $j++;

                           } else {
                              $errors[] = "
                              <div class='alert warning'>
                                  <span class='closebtn'>&times;</span>  
                                  <strong><i class='fas fa-file-excel'></i></strong> Esta imagem Ã© demasiado grande.
                              </div>";                               
                           }

                        } else {
                              $errors[] = "
                              <div class='alert warning'>
                                  <span class='closebtn'>&times;</span>  
                                  <strong><i class='fas fa-plug'></i></strong> Falha ao efetuar o upload. Tente novamente...
                              </div>";   
                        }

                   } else {
                         $errors[] = "
                         <div class='alert warning'>
                              <span class='closebtn'>&times;</span>  
                              <strong><i class='fas fa-file-excel'></i></strong> Ficheiro inv&aacute;lido, tente JPG/JPEG.
                         </div>";  
                   }
               }

          }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php resize image on or before upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12757005/php-resize-image-on-or-before-upload)

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this code in PHP to do compression. The `getimagesize()` function is used to find the size of any given image file and return the dimensions along with the file type.

```
 <?php 
  function compress($source, $destination, $quality) {

    $info = getimagesize($source);

    if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') 
      $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);

    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') 
      $image = imagecreatefromgif($source);

    elseif ($info['mime'] == 'image/png') 
      $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);

    imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality);

    return $destination;
 }

 $source_img = 'source.jpg';
 $destination_img = 'destination .jpg';

 $d = compress($source_img, $destination_img, 90);
```

Comment: ok, but how can i use it in my code.. because… as u see… is complexed xDD

Comment: because i use array[] images….