# uploading videos into a folder and its link to database using PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, video

I am trying to upload a video and save it in a folder as well as savings its path in the database, but the videos are not inserting into the specific folder.

I have searched a lot and found some code. The code is working for images. I have done some modifications from images to videos, but that didn't work.

Here is the parts of my code.

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form_search">
<label>Upload Video Profile:</label>
<span class="form_input">
<input type="file" name="uploadvideo"  />
</span>
</div>

<div class="form_search">
<label> &nbsp;</label>
<span class="form_input">
<input type="submit" name="submitdetails" value="Upload" class="button"/>
</span>
</div>
</form>
```

and my php code to upload video is

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submitdetails']))
{
$name=$_FILES['uploadvideo']['name'];
$type=$_FILES['uploadvideo']['type'];
//$size=$_FILES['uploadvideo']['size'];
$cname=str_replace(" ","_",$name);
$tmp_name=$_FILES['uploadvideo']['tmp_name'];
$target_path="company_profile/";
$target_path=$target_path.basename($cname);
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadvideo']['tmp_name'],$target_path))
{
    echo "hi";
echo $sql="UPDATE employer_logindetails SET (video) VALUES('".$cname."')"; 
$result=mysql_query($sql);
echo "Your video ".$cname." has been successfully uploaded";
}

}

?>
```

Please help me where I am going wrong.

All my `php.ini` modifications are done, and video size is only 7mb.

Comment: what is the error you are getting

Comment: I am not displayed with any errors.the video is not uploading either into folder nor into database.

Comment: If your code worked for images, then it should work just as well for videos. You may have a restriction set somewhere. Theoretically, this should work. I suggest you try the same script you used for your "images" and upload a video with it.

Answer (score 2):

Step-1

This script will allow you to upload files from your browser to your hosting, using PHP. The first thing we need to do is create an HTML form that allows people to choose the file they want to upload.

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
 Please choose a file: <input name="uploaded" type="file" /><br />
 <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
 </form>
```

This form sends data to the file "upload.php", which is what we will be creating next to actually upload the file.

Step-2

The actual file upload is very simple:

```
<?php 
 $target = "upload/"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']) ; 
 $ok=1; 
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 {
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded";
 } 
 else {
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
 }
 ?>
```

This very small piece of code will upload files sent to it by your HTML form.

```
The first line $target = "upload/"; is where we assign the folder that files will be uploaded to. As you can see in the second line, this folder is relative to the upload.php file. So for example, if your file was at www.yours.com/files/upload.php then it would
```

upload files to www.yours.com/files/upload/yourfile.gif. Be sure you remember to create 
this folder! with 777 rights

Step-3

```
 if ($uploaded_size > 350000)
 {
 echo "Your file is too large.<br>"; 
 $ok=0;
 }
```

Assuming that you didn't change the form field in our HTML form (so it is still named uploaded), this will check to see the size of the file. If the file is larger than 350k, they are given a file too large error, and we set $ok to equal 0.

You can change this line to be a larger or smaller size if you wish by changing 350000 to a different number. Or if you don't care about file size, just leave these lines out

```
We are not using $ok=1; at the moment but we will later in the tutorial.

We then move the uploaded file to where it belongs using move_uploaded_file (). This places it in the directory we specified at the beginning of our script. If this fails the user is given an error message, otherwise they are told that the file has been uploaded.
```

Putting All Together

```
<?php 
 $target = "upload/"; 
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['uploaded']['name']) ; 
 $ok=1; 

 //This is our size condition 
 if ($uploaded_size > 350000) 
 { 
 echo "Your file is too large.<br>"; 
 $ok=0; 
 } 

 //This is our limit file type condition 
 if ($uploaded_type =="text/php") 
 { 
 echo "No PHP files<br>"; 
 $ok=0; 
 } 

 //Here we check that $ok was not set to 0 by an error 
 if ($ok==0) 
 { 
 Echo "Sorry your file was not uploaded"; 
 } 

 //If everything is ok we try to upload it 
 else 
 { 
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target)) 
 { 
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded"; 
 } 
 else 
 { 
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
 } 
 } 
 ?>
```

Obviously if you are allowing file uploads you are leaving yourself open to people uploading lots of undesirable things. One precaution is not allowing them to upload any php, html, cgi, etc. files that could contain malicious code. This provides more safety but is not sure fire protection.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: $_FILES['userfile'] in place of $_FILES['uploadvideo'] everywhere.

Comment: thanks.i changed the file name in html form.but nothing is happening

Answer (score 0):

I don'e see any name with `uploadvideo` in your form.

But in php you are using `$_FILES['uploadvideo']`

Try giving the exact name of the file input

e.g.:

```
<input type="file" name="uploadvideo">
```

Comment: I just now modified the question.Please check it now.

Comment: try specifying the max file size at the top of the php script...define ("MAX_SIZE","500");

Comment: that didn't affect anything.Can u please share a link if this was answered earlier somewhere.

Comment: No i have not find something like this. this is just my guess.I will do if i find something exact.